# Property Notification Changed equivalent in C++/CX bindings

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, data-binding, c++-cx

In C#, I often created property getters that returned the result of a function call. This meant that I was required to trigger property change notifications manually using OnPropertyChanged. This process is well documented for C# and VB, but I can't seem to find a C++/CX equivalent. Does such a thing exist, or do I have to find a new programming pattern?

Here's a basic example to show my issue:

```
public:
    property int FooSquared {
        int get() { return _calculateFooSquared(); }
    }

private:
    int _foo;

    int _calculateFooSquared() {
        return _foo * _foo;
    }

    void _setNewFoo(int newFoo) {
        // When _foo gets updated here, anyone bound to FooSquared
        // needs to be updated. How do I trigger an update?
        _foo = newFoo;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you do in c#, implement INotifyPropertyChanged. [MSDN article with samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651573.aspx)

Comment: Simple as that! It always amazes me how well MSDN articles can elude me. Thanks, @LukeN!